# Confused about Type Erasure in Hands-On Design Patterns with C++ by Fedor G. Pikus

Tags: c++, design-patterns, type-erasure

In his book, Fedor G. Pikus talks about type erasure in C++. Specifically, he mentions the example of a smart pointer which has its own deleter whose type is "abstracted away".

This is the example he gives:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class smartptr {

    struct deleter_base {
        virtual void apply(void*) = 0;
        virtual ~deleter_base() { }
    };

    template <typename Deleter>
    struct deleter : public deleter_base {
        deleter (Deleter d) : d_(d) { }
        virtual void apply(void* p) { d_(static_cast<T*>(p)); }
        Deleter d_;
    };

    public:
    template <typename Deleter>
        smartptr(T* p, Deleter d) : p_(p), d_(new deleter<Deleter>(d)) {}
    ~smartptr() { d_->apply(p_); delete d_; }
    T* operator->() { return p_; }
    const T* operator->() const { return p_; }

    private:
    T* p_;
    deleter_base* d_;
};
```

While I understand the implementation for the most part, there is one small thing I can't seem to figure out.

Why do the virtual `apply` methods of the deleter_base and deleter class use `void*` pointers and then `static_cast` to a pointer of type `T*` instead of just being of type `T*` to begin with?

As so:

```cpp
...
    struct deleter_base {
        virtual void apply(T*) = 0;
        virtual ~deleter_base() { }
    };

    template <typename Deleter>
    struct deleter : public deleter_base {
        deleter (Deleter d) : d_(d) { }
        virtual void apply(T* p) { d_(p); }
        Deleter d_;
    };
...
```

Comment: My guess is, having `void*` there allows sharing the deleter between pointers of different types. E.g. `std::shared_ptr<Derived>` is convertible to `std::shared_ptr<Base>` - both share ownership of the object, there's no telling which one would be the last, responsible for deleting it.

Comment: `void*` is how you do type erasure.  it is basically the everything pointer (but not pointer to class members).

Comment: I understand void* is a universal pointer. C uses that extensively. But other than the thing Igor mentioned in his comment, both implementations would be equivalent for someone using the class.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, would that not also require moving the `deleter_base` class out of the template?  Otherwise, `smartptr<Base>::deleter_base` and `smartptr<Derived>::deleter_base` are unrelated types.

Comment: @MattArmstrong Yes, I expect that the deleter machinery, and control block management more generally, is outside of `std::shared_ptr<T>` template - either out of class entirely, or in a common non-template base class.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do the virtual apply methods of the deleter_base and deleter class use void* pointers and then static_cast to a pointer of type T* instead of just being of type T* to begin with?

The answer to your question is simple: taking this example code in isolation, there is no particular reason to use the `void*` and `static_cast<T*>` approach. The code below, with the edits you suggest to replace `void*` with `T*`, works just fine.

I prefer to spell it out as `T*` because it makes the code more clear. It is important to note that the `void*` approach is still correct -- it is always legal to cast a pointer to `void*` and back again.

Using `T*` works because the inner `deleter_base` class is still a template type parameterized on `T`.  In other words, it is a `smartptr<T>::deleter_base` and so has full access to `T`.  In fact, no `smartptr<T>` will ever construct a `deleter_base` that passes anything but a `T*` to its `apply` method.

Using `void*` is a classic C-style approach to type erasure, so the author may have used it out of habit. Or perhaps an earlier design required `void*` and it stayed that way after some revision.

For example, Igor Tandetnik raised the possibility that `void*` leaves room to convert a `smartptr<Derived>` into a `smartptr<Base>` while still using the same deleter object. But, to do this the `T` type must be erased from `deleter_base` as well, which is not the case here (because it is an inner class of the `smartptr<T>` template).

However, the apparent point here is to "type erase away" the `Deleter` type from the `smartptr<T>`, and not require the user to spell the type `smartptr<T, Deleter>`. Both approaches under discussion here accomplish this goal.

```cpp
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class smartptr {
    struct deleter_base {
        virtual void apply(T*) = 0;
        virtual ~deleter_base() {}
    };

    template <typename Deleter>
    struct deleter : public deleter_base {
        deleter(Deleter d) : d_(d) {}
        virtual void apply(T* p) { d_(p); }
        Deleter d_;
    };

   public:
    template <typename Deleter>
    smartptr(T* p, Deleter d) : p_(p), d_(new deleter<Deleter>(d)) {}
    ~smartptr() {
        d_->apply(p_);
        delete d_;
    }
    T* operator->() { return p_; }
    const T* operator->() const { return p_; }

   private:
    T* p_;
    deleter_base* d_;
};

void Code() {
    smartptr<int> foo(new int, std::default_delete<int>());
}
```